# Rebol Is it possible to get the name of the script currently executing?

Tags: rebol

I'm executing multiple libraries from user.r.

I can get the path of the script from system/script/path but I can't see how I can get the name of the script. So am I obliged to hardcode the file name in header property like below (File):

```
REBOL [
    Title: "Lib1"
    File: "lib1.r"
    ]

    script-path: ""
]

system/script/header/script-path: rejoin [system/script/path system/script/header/file]
probe system/script/header/script-path
input
```

Comment: Any reason you use a string! for the file value and not file! ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

system/options/script does only give the full script name and path of the first script passed by dos command line (not if it is executed in console) and not the path of subsequent scripts called by the very first one.

What I want is the full path of the subsequents scripts.

So it seems there's no solution!

Comment: Seems to be right. As you said—you can include the file name in the header, though that does seem flawed.

Answer (score -1):

Try help system/options and you will find the information you are lookimg for.

Comment: As I said above system/options does only work for a script passed to command line not with other scripts executed by parent script.